# Struts 2 with JUnit- Instantiating Action class - class file for com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport not found

Tags: java, exception, junit, struts2, action

I am trying to instantiate a Struts Action class for Unit testing with JUnit.

```
class MyAction extends ActionSupport  implements ServletRequestAware, Preparable {
    // code goes here
}
```

My Unit test class:

```
class MyActionTest {
   MyAction test;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
        test = new MyAction(); // Throws error
   }
}
```

I get this error:

```
[javac] MyActionTest.java:: cannot access com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport
[javac] class file for com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport not found
[javac]         test = new MyAction();
```

What does it actually mean? It cannot find the class in the classpath? (If it is the case, then I thought it would throw ClassDefNotFound exception). Or is it an access issue? or something else?

Comment: Using ant? Try again after `ant clean`.

Comment: @AleksandrM What does it do? And how is it related to the above?